# Which Specflow Visual Studio Plugin version do I need to run SpecFlow 2.2.0?

Tags: specflow

I am not able to determine, which version of the SpecFlow Visual Studio plugin I need to run the old version 2.2.0 of SpecFlow

Due to administrative constraints, we cannot use any other SpecFlow version than 2.2.0

I have tried several older versions of the VS plugin, but with my existing Code (based on SpecFlow 2.2.0), all these result in the error:

```
Error   CS1029  #error: 'Version conflict - SpecFlow Visual Studio extension 
attempted to use SpecFlow code-behind 
generator 1.9, but project 'XXXXXXX' references SpecFlow 2.2.'
```

I suppose that I need some plugin Version, that works internally with 2.2

I cannot use the SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation package, as this is not yet supported with 2.2.0.

Anyone can help me out? The release history of the SpecFlow Visual Studio Plugins can be found here:

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.VisualStudio/releases

*EDIT*

I use Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.6)

In the "packages" folder there are SpecFlow-2.2.0 and SpecFlow.MsTest-2.2.0. I deleted them, I deleted the nuget package Cache and rebuild the solution. 
Problem still exists.

Comment: GitHub issue that you might want to read about: [SpecFlow Generator version 1.9 is used instead of 2.2](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/991).

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have installed? How many different versions of the SpecFlow NuGet package appear under the `packages/` folder of your solution? Is `specflow.exe` in your `%PATH%`?

Comment: Pls see EDIT above. 
`specflow.exe` is not in my `%PATH%`

Comment: I have also tried the `AssemblyBinding` hints from the GitHub issue (see above) without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are seeing has nothing to do with the suggestions in the comments. It is an additional check we added to the extension.

For SpecFlow 2.2 you have to use an older version of the extension. You can find them at https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.VisualStudio/releases

When I am remembering correctly v2017.2.7 should work for it.

Don't forget to turn off automatic updates of the extension. If you do, you will get again the latest version.
Blog post about how to do it is here: https://specflow.org/2018/vs-integration-breaking-changes-affects-all-users/

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the SpecFlow and SpecFlow+ developers.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you install the right Specflow extension for your VS(try uninstall and reinstall as well) also make sure you set "**Enable SpecflowSingleFileGenerator to false**" in **VS>Tools>Options>Specflow**. you only need this to be true for version 3 onward I suppose. 
I had this issue, and while It worked to some extend however, I just install VS 2015 and use specflow 2.2 under that. you should be able to make it work for VS 17 I guess.